# Avoiding rounding with formatC

Tags: r, string

I am using `formatC` to ensure that a bunch of numbers are all printed to the same length. Some numbers are shorter than the desired length and padded with 0s, and some are longer and truncated. The issue is that `formatC` rounds in the last digit.

This is fine

```
> formatC(1, digits = 5, format = 'f')
[1] "1.00000"
```

I do not like the rounding, I would rather truncate it at the nth digit **without** rounding.

```
> formatC(1.234567, digits = 5, format = 'f')
[1] "1.23457"
```

Is there a way to truncate numbers without rounding in R? I understand that it could be possible to first convert to character and then grab a certain substring of that, but that feels clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hacky, but you can use `trunc` with a little multiplication:

```
trunc(1.234567 * 1e5) / 1e5
# [1] 1.23456
```

Functionalize it:

```
trunc2 = function(x, d) trunc(x * 10 ^ d) / 10 ^ d
```

Then you can

```
formatC(trunc2(1.234567, 5), digits = 5, format = 'f')
# [1] "1.23456"
```

Comment: I like this because it works with pipes as well. Just insert a `trunc2` before the `formatC`.